# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable - predict(samples(1,72100,1))

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, conv-neural-network

**What is the problem here as I am using this instruction to give me a script from a cnn trainer model for speech recognition**
**This instruction converts a recording to text for the cnn model for speech recognition, and it is recorded by the laptop mike.**

```
#reading the voice commands
samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(filepath , sr = 16000)
ipd.Audio(samples,rate=16000)

 predict(samples(1,72100,1))
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is predict and what does the function samples() do? Include the code in the question.

Comment: [Please give a minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also post full traceback.

Comment: samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(filepath , sr = 16000)
ipd.Audio(samples,rate=16000)    predict(samples(1,72100,1))

Comment: this me code     https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nvP_1MG2cPnnsoQlv_pPIQnkD0RsH1mY?usp=sharing

Comment: Add it to the question and explain what exactly is the code supposed to do?